# The Javamail example from java2s.com

Tags: java

i tried the example from java2s.com with the help of Joe Tuskan and others i resolved some bugs.
Now at the end of the code i want to understand the condition:

```
//...
String disposition = messages[i].getDisposition();
if (disposition == null) { 
    ; // do nothing
} else if (disposition.equals(Part.INLINE)) {
    System.out.println("This part should be displayed inline")
//...
```

What is disposition? and apparently in my gmailaccount the `disposition = null`, why?
And how can i resolve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This memo defines a [RFC-MIME-MEDIA] content-type for message
disposition notifications (MDNs).  An MDN can be used to notify the
sender of a message of any of several conditions that may occur after
successful delivery, such as display of the message contents,
printing of the message, deletion (without display) of the message,
or the recipient's refusal to provide MDNs.  The
"message/disposition-notification" content-type defined herein is
intended for use within the framework of the "multipart/report"
content type defined in [RFC-REPORT].

This memo defines the format of the notifications and the [RFC-
MSGFMT] headers used to request them.

From here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3798

Comment: my IT education level is too low to understand ur answer, but thx